# opengl glDrawArray throws exception

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm new to openGL and I need to directly use it for debuging perpose can anyone please tell me why in this code glDrawArray should throw exception (trying to access memory at 0x00000000)

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
float data[8];
data[0] = 10;
data[1] = 10; 
data[2] = 10;
data[3] = 20; 
data[4] = 20;
data[5] = 20; 
data[6] = 20;
data[7] = 10; 
glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,data);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,4);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Do you call this with valid GL context? Maybe you call it from the wrong thread

Comment: my program only have one thread, so it can't be called from a wrong thread.

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: it'll be just copying and pasting a GameEngine, i've just added these lines to draw function of one of it's samples. if you are still curious about the full source code you can download cocos2d-x and in helloworld sample override draw funciton of `class HelloWorld` and add these lines to it. in another sample these code works perfectly so i think there should be some preperations before calling them but i couldn't find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have enabled another array with `glEnableClientState` at another point in your program and didn't disable it. So `glDrawArrays` tries to read from another array that causes the problem.

**EDIT:**: It could also be, that the code you showed us is not the real code and you call `glVertexPointer` at a completely different place than `glDrawArrays`. When giving `data` as vertex pointer, you only tell it to take the vertices from `data`, when `glDrawArrays` is called. The vertex data is not copied, so `data` has to still exist when `glDrawArrays` is called (at the moment it's a local variable, but with the code snippet you gave us it should work).

**EDIT:** I also suppose you are not using any buffer objects, as that could also be a problem, if a vertex buffer is bound when you call `glVertexPointer`.

Comment: i'm not sure about that but I think that isn't the case, cuase that would throw exception like `access violation while trying to access 0x0000000` it seems the array i'm passing to `glVertexPointer` is not stored at all.

Comment: @Gajet But isn't this the error you mention in your question?

Comment: @christian :yes that's the same problem, and that's exactly the code that is generating exception. you are correct it's main use is comething else in somewhere else but when i moved it to my main draw call there it caused same problem so I just pasted this code, the main use was to draw debug info of box2d objects.

Comment: @Gajet The fact that you are not sure about that, shows me that you really don't completely know, in what state other parts of your program leave the GL. So investigating that issue would be a good idea. Just try to call `glDisableClientState` on all other arrays. PS.: The array is not stored, only its address is (look at my udpated answer).

Comment: after disabling GL_COLOR_ARRAY and GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY exception is fixed but it still doesn't draw any thing on the screen and ideas?

Comment: @Gajet Without some more code I have completely no idea. But I suppose you should look into the other functions and check in what state the GL really is, as it seems this was exactly the cause for the exception.

Comment: found that i hade to call `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`,it fixed all and restore all states to normal after calling glDrawArray but i can't get why without disableing some things that I don't use in my code, it throws exceptions. anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: @Gajet I just guess another part of your program enables it, so you have to disable it again. OpenGL is a state machine, so if you do not restore the state you set, it will remain set, at least until you destroy the complete context and create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Your `glDrawArrays` call is equivalent to:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex2fv(data +  0);
glVertex2fv(data +  2);
glVertex2fv(data +  4);
glVertex2fv(data +  6);
glVertex2fv(data +  8);
glVertex2fv(data + 10);
glVertex2fv(data + 12);
glVertex2fv(data + 14);
glEnd();
```

So you are definitely trying to access some memory outside of `data`.

Comment: Like tibur said. the 8 in `glDrawArrays` should be the number of vertices to draw and not the number of floats.

Comment: Does you application crash if you replace your `glDrawArray` by the glBegin/glEnd equivalent code? (With only the first 4 `glVertex2fv` calls)

Comment: i tried to do so but i'm developing a game for Iphone and it seems OpenGLES doesn't have `glBegin` or `glEnd`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,4);
```

In your call to glVertexPointer() you are saying that each vertex has two floats. But in the call to glDrawArrays() you don't specify the number of elements in the array, you specify the number of coordinates, in this case they are four.

Comment: tibur also suggested that but I still get error after that fix.